# VBA Subscript out of range error when saving file?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting an error on the Filename line saying that subscript is out of range. I've the file name critea on a sheet called Fname

```
Set xl = ActiveWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Path = "S:\Common\Central\"
Filename = xl.Sheets("Fname").Range("A7").Value
xl.SaveAs Path & Filename & ".xlsx"
xl.Close
```

Comment: Sheet name probably has leading or trailing whitespace. Or the active workbook is not the workbook with the sheet in it.

Comment: try change `activeworkbook` to `thisworkbook` (if target sheet is on workbook with macro)

Comment: I get the same error. What should I do to set it as the ActiveWorkbook?

Comment: So I remove the Set xl = ActiveWorkbook statement and I no longer get an error on Filename but I get a new on the next line to SaveAs.

The new error is Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Are there maybe two workbooks involved in this code? If it is only one, is it the one containing this code? If it is two, please clarify which is which. I mean, you may be reading the file name from one workbook, and then saving another workbook with this file name.

Answer (score 0):

My advice to you is as follows:

declarate global variables in standard modules like

```
    Public wb As Workbook
    Public ws As Worksheet
    
    Sub startupSettings()
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheetname")
    End Sub
```

you can call this procedure by worbook open event in thisworkbook code like

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    startupSettings
End Sub
```

or every time as first when you lunch procedures

```
Sub someSub()
    startupSettings
    '.... code
End Sub
```

then your save file procedure looks like

```
option explicit

Sub saveMyFile()
    Dim path As String, fileName As String
    startupSettings '   if variables not set before
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    path = "S:\Common\Central\"
    fileName = ws.Range("A7").Value
    wb.SaveAs path & fileName & ".xlsx" ' if you save workbook with macro that line return error should be .xlsm or another procedure with workbook.add
    wb.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: to make the code readable always use main sub when u lunch subrutines and functions

Answer (score 0):

### Backup Workbook

- If you turn off [`Application.DisplayAlerts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts) before saving, you won't see any dialog (overwrite, file format,...) and the file will be automatically overwritten. Don't forget to turn it on again.
- When saving files, you should always use a parameter for the second argument [`FileFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat). In your case, it is `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` for `.xlsx` files.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub backupWorkbook()
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "S:\Common\Central\"

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' any workbook that is selected
    
    Dim BaseName As String: BaseName = wb.Worksheets("Fname").Range("A7").Value

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.SaveAs FolderPath & BaseName & ".xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    wb.Close

End Sub
```